# Unable To Access PHP Global Variable

Tags: php

I am trying to pull global variable $nsfw but it shows nothing at all. If I echo it inside function, it works. But outside, it fails even when defined as global. Kindly help me out here.

```
 <?php    
    if(!function_exists('do_example_work'))
    {
        function do_example_work()
        {
            global $nsfw;

        include("includes/dbconnect.php");
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASS, $DBNAME);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT fieldname FROM table WHERE name='$anything'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row["fieldname"] == 1) {
            // do somethin
            $nsfw = 25;
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "enjoy";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
            }
        echo $nsfw;
};


?>
```

Comment: How and when are you setting `$nsfw`?

Comment: Can you not find an alternative to using a global? Like inject the data into the function `function do_example_work($nsfw)`?

Comment: I just need a way to get that $nsfw defined inside while loop to show up at bottom of page. Anyone knows a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are arguments for and against Globals. You can search Stack and the internet and read about:

1. Globals are bad in many ways, and should be avoided where possible
2. Globals are not bad, and can be fine/safe to use if you know what you are
   doing

---

The manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

You seem to be over complicating things with this basic user defined function.

### OUT

If you want to get data **out** of a function, just use the *[return](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)* statement

```
function do_example_work() {

  // Do some stuff here
  $nsfw = 25;

  return $nsfw; // Return where needed, in conditional statement or end of function

}

// Will echo "25"
echo do_example_work();
```

---

### IN

FYI:

To get data **into** the function from outside, just pass the data into your function from the outside as an argument:

```
function do_example_work($nsfw) {

/** The var "$nsfw" will have whatever data you pass in through the function call
 * You can use it as required - check if $nsfw == something
 * Or it might be database login details (urgh)
 */

echo $nsfw." - And words from in the function"; 

}

// Will echo "Pass in argument - And words from in the function"
do_example_work("Pass in argument");
```

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `global` in front of a variable name means that the variable is defined somewhere outside the function, and now I want to use that variable. It does not generate a global variable. So you need to define the variable outside the function, and then you can use that variable inside a function using the `global` keyword in front of it.
In your code I cannot see you defining the variable outside the function. You are just echoing it out at the bottom of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason for keeping global variable inside method ?? Move it outside method and it should work for u.

Or
Try GLOBALS as shown below.

```
function doit() { $GLOBALS['val'] = 'bar'; } doit(); echo $val;
```

Gives the output as :

bar

Or

```
<?php 
foo(); 
bar(); 

function foo() { global $jabberwocky; $jabberwocky="test data<br>"; bar(); } function bar() { global $jabberwocky; echo $jabberwocky; } ?>
```